# Patch Delta Is Null when entity has children

Tags: odata, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using AspNet Core Boilerplate and when trying to update an entity with children with patch in a odata controller I end up with a null delta parameter. Works fine if the entity has no children. Seems to be related to the post below, how can I apply this to AbpODataEntityController.

https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/964

My entities look similar to this, so when there are changes to entities in the Items collection is when the issue occurs.

```
public class Float : FullAuditedEntity<int>, IMustHaveTenant
{
    [InverseProperty("Float")]
    public ICollection<FloatItem> Items { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OutletId")]
    public virtual int OutletId { get; set; }
    public Outlet Outlet { get; set; }

}

public class FloatItem : FullAuditedEntity<int>, IMustHaveTenant
{
    [ForeignKey("Float")]
    public virtual int FloatId { get; set; }
    public Float Float { get; set; }

    public virtual double CountValue { get; set; }
}
```